# Creating partition on USB drive

Tags: macos, usb, disk-utility, bootable-disk

I have been following directions to create a bootable USB drive from here:

http://borgstrom.ca/2010/10/14/os-x-bootable-usb.html

Here is the relevant screenshot:

[image]

However for my case on the USB Drive (a new 32GB Sandisk): the Disk Utility shows the `Partition` tab is disabled:

[image]

Hints on whether the procedure being followed were incorrect appreciated.

Comment: If you have an answer, consider putting that in the answer and not editing it into the post. What arrangement do you require of the 32 GB space?

Comment: @bmike  I did not want to create another answer to conflict with yours. But given your comment I will do so - but refer back to yours from mine. I have seen others do both ways in the past - I'm fine with it.  afa arrangement: bootable iso

Comment: @bmike  You may feel it were fine to delete (multiple/all) comments on your answers - apparently it is your prerogative. Not the preferred approach from here. But yea it's your call.

Comment: Great - I'm happy to delete my answer - I don't need more or more votes :-) was more interested in others knowing what the answer was

Comment: Comments get all sorts of flags when they are chatty- they are ephemeral so be sure to put details in the post themselves.

Comment: @bmike Your answer has been helpful.  My additions were just that - additions and refinements. Please keep your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple declines to partition many more drives on 10.11 than it did in the past. Have you tried the "erase" command to blow away everything?

If that's no good, you could try the command line:

```
diskutil splitpartition
```

The help is a bit obtuse, but if you posted what layout you wanted, perhaps someone could get you the command for OS X.

> Split a pre-existing partition into multiple partitions.  All data on the split
>   partition will be lost.  The first disk parameter is the one to split; the
>   remaining parameters are as in the diskutil partitionDisk command.
>   Ownership of the affected disk is required.
>
> Valid sizes are floating-point numbers with a suffix of B(ytes), S(512-byte-
>   blocks), K(ilobytes), M(egabytes), G(igabytes), T(erabytes), P(etabytes),
>   or (%)percentage of the total size of the whole disk.

Here's a lot of output from a command to make three partitions on a 64 GB drive:

```
$ diskutil splitpartition disk2s2 "MS-DOS FAT12" BOOT_ARMHF 1.0M ExFAT Linux 1.9G "Journaled HFS+" OSX 2G
Started partitioning on disk2s2 Untitled
Splitting
Unmounting disk
Waiting for the disks to reappear
Formatting disk2s2 as MS-DOS (FAT12) with name BOOT_ARMHF
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk2s2: 1907 sectors in 1907 FAT12 clusters (512 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=1 res=1 nft=2 rde=512 sec=1952 mid=0xf8 spf=6 spt=32 hds=16 hid=409640 drv=0x80
Mounting disk
Formatting disk2s3 as ExFAT with name Linux
Volume name      : Linux
Partition offset : 411648 sectors (210763776 bytes)
Volume size      : 3708928 sectors (1898971136 bytes)
Bytes per sector : 512
Bytes per cluster: 131072
FAT offset       : 16384 sectors (8388608 bytes)
# FAT sectors    : 16384
Number of FATs   : 1
Cluster offset   : 32768 sectors (16777216 bytes)
# Clusters       : 14360
Volume Serial #  : 56c61e6c
Bitmap start     : 2
Bitmap file size : 1795
Upcase start     : 3
Upcase file size : 5836
Root start       : 4
Mounting disk
Formatting disk2s4 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name OSX
Initialized /dev/rdisk2s4 as a 57 GB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 8192k journal
Mounting disk
Finished partitioning on disk2s2 Untitled
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *63.9 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOT_ARMHF              999.4 KB   disk2s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Linux                   1.9 GB     disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS OSX                     61.6 GB    disk2s4
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested by @bmike I have moved this to a separate answer (away from the original question).  Please refer to his answer as the recommended one: this one is more of "further details".

Here is the specific command the result

```
$diskutil splitPartition /Volumes/ubuntu_1404/ 1 exFAT  ubuntu 30G
Started partitioning on disk3s1 ubuntu_1404
Splitting
Unmounting disk
Waiting for the disks to reappear
Formatting disk3s1 as ExFAT with name ubuntu
Volume name      : ubuntu
Partition offset : 32 sectors (16384 bytes)
Volume size      : 58593744 sectors (29999996928 bytes)
Bytes per sector : 512
Bytes per cluster: 32768
FAT offset       : 2048 sectors (1048576 bytes)
# FAT sectors    : 8192
Number of FATs   : 1
Cluster offset   : 10240 sectors (5242880 bytes)
# Clusters       : 915367
Volume Serial #  : 56c61d6b
Bitmap start     : 2
Bitmap file size : 114421
Upcase start     : 6
Upcase file size : 5836
Root start       : 7
Mounting disk
Finished partitioning on disk3s1 ubuntu_1404
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *30.8 GB    disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS ubuntu                  30.0 GB    disk3s1
```